# Not able to Create HANA Stored Procedure in Repository of Development Perspective

Tags: hana

I have been trying to create Stored Procedure in the repository section of HANA Development perspective.
Even though I can see my schema in repository, I dont see the create procedure option.

Can you please help me here.
Am I missing any authorization?
Any other way to create(Path) 
Version using - HANA 1.0 SPS 12

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you cannot create HANA database procedure from HANA Development Perspective. There you will be able to create DB procedure proxy object. And for that you have to create database procedure before.

You can [create HANA database procedure](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/create-stored-procedure-on-hana-database-using-hdbprocedure.aspx) on the Repositories tab under a package.
Then you will be able call it using CALL statement

Or you can [create database procedure](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/create-procedure-on-sap-hana-database.aspx) directly on the database using SQLScript

Please check the referred samples, I hope they help for a solution